# Sort lightning datatable by default

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, sort

My sort function works fine, but I the table should be sorted by default.
How can I sort the table by date (dateOut) by default?

**CONTROLLER**

```
doInIt : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.mycolumns', [
        {label: "date",             fieldName: 'dateOut',       sortable: true,     type: "date-local",     initialWidth: 90,       typeAttributes: {month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit" } },           
        {label: 'subject',          fieldName: 'subjectIdOut',  sortable: true,     type: 'url',            initialWidth: 650,      typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'subjectOut' }, target: '_blank'} },       
    ]);

handleSort: function(component,event,helper){           
    var sortBy = event.getParam("fieldName");            
    var sortDirection = event.getParam("sortDirection");           
    component.set("v.sortBy", sortBy);
    component.set("v.sortDirection", sortDirection);            
    helper.sortData(component, sortBy, sortDirection);
}
```

**HELPER**

```
({
    sortData : function(component, fieldName, sortDirection){
        var data = component.get("v.taskEventList2");
        var key = function(a) { return a[fieldName]; }
        var reverse = sortDirection == 'asc' ? 1: -1;             
        data.sort(function(a,b){
                var a = key(a) ? key(a) : '';
                var b = key(b) ? key(b) : '';
                return reverse * ((a>b) - (b>a));
            });
        component.set("v.taskEventList2",data);
    }
})
```

Comment: If you are retrieving the data from apex by SOQL, you can add sorting to SOQL itself.

Comment: @Raul you are right, but I have a wrapper list which contains a lot of lists and I need to sort the list by the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading the data, sort the results then:

```
const action = component.get('c.getData');
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
  if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
    component.set('v.taskEventList2', response.getReturnValue());
    helper.sort(component, 'dateOut', 'asc');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

by default- so when the table appears it should be sorted, is it that way FenTro?
Then probably the lightning data table can be conditionally rendered in UI once sorting is done, showing spinner until then.

Kindly try

```
<aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="boolean" default="true"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
<lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="medium" />
  <aura:set attribute="else">
   <!-- your lightning data table here -->
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

```
HELPER


    ({
    sortData : function(component, fieldName, sortDirection){
        var data = component.get("v.taskEventList2");
        var key = function(a) { return a[fieldName]; }
        var reverse = sortDirection == 'asc' ? 1: -1;             
        data.sort(function(a,b){
                var a = key(a) ? key(a) : '';
                var b = key(b) ? key(b) : '';
                return reverse * ((a>b) - (b>a));
            });
        component.set("v.taskEventList2",data);
        //reset the boolean once sorting is done
        component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
    }
})
```